# logback.xml:How to make 'debug' logs in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Is  there any way  i can  change  `<root level="INFO">` to `<root level="DEBUG">`
in logback.xml if  i don't  have  physical connection to nifi app ? 
I mean  is there any command  which  can  help me change this attribute?

Comment: You wants to change log only  'Debug' level,right?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 5):

You can only change the log levels by editing logback.xml on the machine where it resides.